# Test the hypothesis that the means are equal. Use PROC MEANS to generate descriptive statistics for the four groups

Tags: sas

Consider an experiment to study four types of fertilizer, labeled 1, 2, 3, and 4. One fertilizer is chemical and the rest are organic. You want to see whether the average weights of the garlic bulbs are significantly different for plants in beds that use different fertilizers.
Test the hypothesis that the means are equal. Use PROC MEANS to generate descriptive statistics for the four groups, and use PROC SGPLOT to produce box plots of bulb weight for the four groups. Submit the code and view the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
proc means data=dataset; 
   var BulbWt;
   class Fertilizer;
  
run;

proc sgplot data=dataset;
    vbox BulbWt / category=Fertilizer 
                  connect=mean;
run;
```